# Fallout 4 crashes so hard it gives Steam a concussion

Tags: steam, fallout-4, windows-10

This has happened to me twice now - the first time I assumed it was just some weird fluke because this problem is bizarre. OS is Windows 10 FWIW.

Fallout 4 will freeze and I am unable to access the task manager to end the application (a black overlay from the game covers up the entire desktop - even though I can open the Task Manager using using Ctrl+Alt+Delete I can't actually see the running processes). Right clicking the Fallout icon -> close window does nothing. I have to force restart the computer in order to get out of this situation. This is annoying but I can live with it (Bethesda games, amirite?).

*The problem* is that when the computer boots up and I start Steam, Steam no longer thinks that Fallout is installed. The game still exists on disk and Windows recognizes that it's there, but Steam refuses to acknowledge it. I have to "reinstall" the game (essentially Steam verifies that all of the needed files are present). *That* is annoying. Even though I don't need to re-download and re-install the game, it still takes Steam between 5 and 10 minutes to check that the game is still present.

Any thoughts? If I can stop the freezing that would be great (losing progress in Survival mode through no fault of my own isn't what I would call fun) but I'll settle for Steam not suffering from short term amnesia.

---

Response to comment questions:

> is there any pattern to the crashes?

<s>Not that I can tell.</s> Happened again when entering VATS - that seems to be the culprit.

> What are you doing when it happens?

The last time it happened was when entering VATS during a Gunner attack on Sanctuary (e.g., VATS noise played, zoomed in, freeze). I don't remember what I was doing the first time.

> When did this start happening? Right after initial installation? Months later? Did you install some DLC or mod before it began?

Roughly a week and a half ago. No mods, but I do have Automaton, Wasteland Workshop, and now that I think about it, I was on the beta release for Survival mode. That might be relevant.

> What's the situation when the game begins operating again? Lose any saves?

The game itself appears to be undamaged, at least so far. No corrupted saves/lost data.

Comment: I don't really have any ideas, but here are some questions: is there any pattern to the crashes? What are you doing when it happens? When did this start happening? Right after initial installation? Months later? Did you install some DLC or mod before it began? What's the situation when the game begins operating again? Lose any saves?

Comment: @DCShannon edited some info in

Comment: In recovering from crashes, have you tried Windows+Tab and opening a new desktop? Windows 10 allows parallel desktops that *should* allow you to run task manager w/o the black screen.

Comment: @Dallium now there's a thought. I haven't really gone digging into the new W-10 features, that sounds handy

Comment: Well-constructed question

Comment: Do you experience the same problem with the release version instead of the beta?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs not yet but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: As many beta users often say: Beta is Beta. It is entirely possible that this is a beta-exclusive bug that will be ironed out in a later Beta version or maybe the final release.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs indeed that is true, however I know a thing or two about software bugs and I find it very difficult (although not impossible) to believe that a "beta bug" would result in errors _in an entirely different application_. Now that being said this is Bethesda - they don't have bugs, they've got radroaches.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in Steam. i think that the issue is in how FO4 is coded and handles interruptions, Causing steam to think that FO4 isn't installed. The freezing issues are just entirely different bugs with the Survival Mode Beta. However, because you essentially shut down the computer without due care, the other bug surfaces. there's a good chance that Elias' Task Manager fix causes the same bug.

Comment: AFAIK, it is out of beta. I know my fallout 4 install is no longer flagged as beta as of an update maybe 1 or 2 days ago. A major disk error might account for both the freezing and the invalid state of the game file(s).

Comment: @Dallium I was able to use your new desktop suggestion last night, worked a charm.

Comment: Windows has a rare, uhm, lets call it feature? that when the system crashes in certain circumstances, a file being open (just read only!) can be corrupted and upon reboot is being removed entirely sometimes. I have had this happen numerous times with parts of the nvidia driver files and wow crashing. The solution to that for me was to determine which files went missing (you can do that by comparing right after the crash with after "reinstall") and add some re-deployment of those files to autostart or whatever it is these days with winX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem with Skyrim. You can't fully avoid it, but you can go to your Task Manager -> Options -> Always on Top. It will now always be above the Crashed game so you can close it. You can then safely restart it.

Comment: Good call. If there are no better solutions (and this works) this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Sadly no, there isn't. Luckily it's not dangerous to your save or something just really annoying.

Comment: I noticed this as well when I upgraded to windows-10. "Always on top" defaulted to "disabled."